# How to access a method from another classes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

In **CalViewController** class I have **showCal** method

```
-(IBAction) showCal{

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
if ([viewMainView superview]) {
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [viewMainView removeFromSuperview];   
    [self.view addSubview:viewCalView];
}
}
```

I want to call it from **CustomCell** class, which is a separate class with xib for custom cell.
I tried like this, (buttonPressed method associate with a button in the custom cell).

```
-(IBAction) buttonPressed{
CalViewController *objCalViewController=[[calViewController alloc] init];
[objCalViewController showCal];

}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Try to replace `-(IBAction) showCal` with `-(void) showCal`. Does compiler show warning at line `[objCalViewController showCal];`?

Comment: CalViewController *objCalViewController=[[calViewController alloc] iinitWithNibName:@"CalViewController" bundle:nil]; try like dis .i tried with ibaction its also calling both are view controllers.

Comment: you didnt add  calview as a subview to the current view...the animation will work only on tat viewcontroler..since u have set forView as self.view...

Comment: I change as -(void) showCal. compiler does not show any warning. but still have the problem

Comment: @booleanBoy, thanks a lot, that is the case. But how can I solve it? if you can, please give me a sample

Comment: could u please explain ur scenario more clearly...like wat kind of animation u wish to achieve ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[objCalViewController showCal]; put a break point before it and change the function to -(void)showCal and don't forget to put the -(void)showCal in .h file of CalViewController class hope it will works for you :)

Comment: thanks a lot guys, it works. method is called. But problem is the way I implemented showCal method. that means the animation is not work :(

Answer (score 3):

You can call a user methods `[objCalViewController showCal];` in this way But there is no way you can call a `IBAction` method of another class simply make the function as  `-(void) showCal`